# PHP script just hangs on large file uploads

Tags: post, file-upload, upload, php

I have a php script that allows users to upload multiple files to server on POST, then redirect to next page.

It seems to have been working for some time but lately users are reporting it hanging infinitely. They input all fields, select files to upload, hit post, then wait for hours then give up and close the window. But when I check it appears the files were successfully uploaded and in tact. Just the fields were not posted.

It seems the script cannot transition to the next section where form fields get parsed and inserted to mysql database. I've did some small tests and cannot recreate the problem. Although I don't have the time to test with large files such as 200M.

The max total filesize any user would upload would be 200M so I feel my php core settings are sufficient. Here is what I have:

```
max_execution_time = 7200
max_file_uploads = 20
max_input_time = 7200
memory_limit = 8000M
output_buffering = 4096
upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

Anything else in the core settings that could perhaps be giving me this problem? Or would it be a browser problem?

Comment: 200M is an unusually high upload limit...you may want to consider ftp file transfers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely your users' connection speed. Ask one of your users their connection speed and to use Google Chrome and look at the status bar, it should increment the percentage of the progress of the upload. Or I recommend trying this yourself and throttling your bandwidth someone. Remember your users most likely have a maximum of 1.5 up unless they have Fios or a better connection (e.g. T1).

Comment: Agreed... a 200MB file can take a long time (30-60 minutes) to upload even on a cable or DSL connection (e.g. 200000 KB / 100 KB/s).